# Geometric meaning of the Kernel of a Fundamental Group Map

Tags: algebraic-topology

For simplicity let X,Y be path connected topological spaces. A continous map $$f:X \rightarrow Y $$ induces a map on of the fundamental groups
$$\bar{f}: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y)$$
Is there a geometric way to understand $ker(\bar{f})$? If $Y$ quotient space of $X$, one seem to be able to find a geometric meaning. Is there a geometric meaning for the general case?

Comment: These are the non-contractible paths in $X$ which map to contractible paths in $Y$. What else could be said for a general $f$?

Comment: Be careful with quotients because there are many cases where $Y$ is a quotient space of $X$ but the induced map on fundamental groups is still injective, for example in the case where $f\colon X\to Y$ is a covering space, or where $f\colon [0,1] \to S^1$ is the map that identifies the boundary points. Sometimes forming a quotient space only introduces *new* non-contractible loops.